# Wrong starting folder in Gnome programs under KDE

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde, kubuntu

I originally installed ubuntu but switched to using kde. Now every gnome programs (e.g. gnome-terminal or gedit) start with ~/Downloads as standard folder. gedit always wants to save in ~/Downloads and gnome-terminal puts me in ~/Downloads. Konsole doesn't. What do I have to change to set this right?

Answer (score 1):

for some reason KDE uses the "DocumentPath" for all these, changing it to ~ does the trick, but is there a nicer way still?